# Calling a self-hosted WCF service in windows svc without blocking the UI

Tags: c#, winforms, wcf

I have a WCF service hosted in a windows svc. I execute it in the normal way from a winforms app, making the channel etc, and then calling the method. There's no .svc file on the server side.

However, when I call the method in the windows service from the gui, this blocks the UI. Is there a way to do this without blocking the UI?

Thanks

Comment: So you have a client application that has a gui, that is then calling the WCF service hosted in the UI?

Comment: No the WCF service is hosted in a windows service. Sorry I noticed that my post was a little unclear, I've clarified it now.

Comment: Are you calling the WCF service from a separate thread in the UI?

Comment: It's called from within a backgroundworker (in a backgroundworker's dowork method). Maybe I need this on the service implementation: ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode:=ConcurrencyMode.Reentrant, UseSynchronizationContext:=False)

Comment: Its weird because if you call your WCF service from a background thread it should never block your UI even if the WCF service call never comes back.

Comment: Hmmm I'll need to play with the code a little.

Comment: Are u calling the service from backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) and running the worker using RunWorkerAsync()..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at either the BackgroundWorker class, or the newer Task Parallel Library stuff. What you want is to fire off a call to the service, and describe what to do when the answer is received, but not block the UI while waiting for the answer. In some cases, there may be nothing for the UI to *do* while it waits for the answer, such as in the case of a search dialog. Until the answer comes back, there's really nothing else the UI can be doing. But executing the search in the background means that the UI *thread* has been freed. This means that you should still be able to move and resize the window, or possibly switch to another form in the same application while you wait. This is a good enough reason to execute the calls in the background.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the Async methods?
For each method that is generated for you by the IDE, there is another method with Async suffix. This way you can asynchronously call the webservice.

Comment: Is it that simple though? I looked at this, but it seems like I need a .svc file?

Comment: How are you calling the service now? Inprocess ot through the network? What binding? Http? netTcp? Etc?

Comment: Right now its named pipes (two processes on same machine). Anyway, I've done the async way and it works so far, but needs some modifications.